# SQL UPDATE stored procedure from Visual studio

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have an  UPDATE stored procedure that works good from SQL Server query:

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMedicalCard]
@RecordingCode int,
@BeginTreatmentDate date,
@EndTreatmentDate date,
@MainDiagnosis nchar(100),
@AttendantDiagnosis nchar(100),
@TreatmentResult nchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MedicalCard
    SET BeginTreatmentDate = @BeginTreatmentDate,
        EndTreatmentDate = @EndTreatmentDate,
        MainDiagnosis = @MainDiagnosis,
        AttendantDiagnosis = @AttendantDiagnosis,
        TreatmentResult = @TreatmentResult
    WHERE RecordingCode = @RecordingCode
END
```

But when i call this procedure from Visual studio it does not update.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Policlinic;Integrated Security=SSPI";

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.CommandText = "UpdateMedicalCard";

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@RecordingCode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            myCommand.Parameters["@RecordingCode"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@BeginTreatmentDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
            myCommand.Parameters["@BeginTreatmentDate"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndTreatmentDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
            myCommand.Parameters["@EndTreatmentDate"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value;

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@MainDiagnosis", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar);
            myCommand.Parameters["@MainDiagnosis"].Value = "qwe";

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@AttendantDiagnosis", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar);
            myCommand.Parameters["@AttendantDiagnosis"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TreatmentResult", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar);
            myCommand.Parameters["@TreatmentResult"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value;

            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
        connection.Close();
```

I think  i do smth wrong at the last 4 rows. Help please.

Answer (score 2):

Your command isn't going to return any result rows, so you don't need to use a DataTable or DataAdapter. You just need to call `connection.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.

You may also want to double check that the data (specifically the dates, as they can be tricky since the field may or may not also store a time component depending on how the table is defined, match an existing row.